# Do level 3 crafting patterns drop in Looking For Raid difficulty?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm trying to complete my Leatherworking and Enchanting patterns. I've probably done Emerald Nightmare like a dozen times, on LFR, normal and Heroic, but I still am lacking most recipes from raids and dungeons.

Do these even drop on LFR difficulty?

Comment: Afaik only mount recipes (steelbound harness) don't drop on LFR difficulty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this enchanting](http://www.wowhead.com/legion-enchanting-guide) guide, it shows beside each Rank 3 Enchantment that it is found by `World Creatures`.

But, looking at the actual boss drops for [Xavius](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=103769/xavius#drops:mode=lfr:0+19+1) for example, the rank 3 enchanting options are no longer visible when switching between LFR and normal.

Therefor no, LFR cannot give rank 3 enchantments.

Answer (score 0):

According to Wowhead, rank 3 drops only on normal and above, with a very small percentage drop rate:

[LFR - No Mark of the Distant Army](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=106087/elerethe-renferal#drops:mode=lfr)

[Normal - Rank 3 Mark of the Distant Army, 0.3% drop rate](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=106087/elerethe-renferal#drops:mode=n)

Heroic is listed as 1.1% and mythic 0.4%. Unfortunately, these rates are plagued by the issue that not all captured encounters have enchanters there and even if they do some people would already have the rank 3 formula and would therefore be ineligible to have it drop for them.

Comment: You probably got the links mixed up. They both show normal loot..?

Comment: The links work fine for me. The LFR one ends in #drops:mode=lfr and shows 21 items, the normal one ends in #drops:mode=n, shows 23 items, and also shows the rank 3 formula in the loot table.

Comment: Strange.. I need the mode=raidfinder to display the right items.

Comment: Strange indeed. If I was not in the middle of a business trip I would try to edit some screen captures as illustrations for the answer. I will try to keep a mental note to do that when I get back home to my good PC.